# python: split dataframe in multiple dataframes with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df_portfolio. I want to split this dataframe in 3 different dataframes based on the ticker column and the ownership column.

I cant get my code to work. This is what I have so far, but it returns an empty dataframe.

```
# split dataframe 
print('splitting dataframe per ticker and ownership ... ')

# set up empty dataframes
df_vusa = pd.DataFrame() 
df_iaex = pd.DataFrame() 
df_vwrl = pd.DataFrame()

# create lists to loop through
df_list = [df_vusa, df_iaex, df_vwrl] 
my_tickers = ['VUSA.AS', 'IAEX.AS', 'VWRL.AS']

# for loop
for df, ticker in zip(df_list,my_tickers):
    df = df_portfolio.loc[df_portfolio['ticker'] == ticker]
    df = df.loc[df['ownership'] == True]
```

Comment: Variable "df" is overwritten at beginning of each iteration of the for-loop. You must store the dataframe at the end of each iteration, e. g. append it to a list.

Comment: `dfs = [df_portfolio[df_portfolio['ticker'] == ticker].copy() for ticker in my_tickers]`? Or perhaps dictionary comprehension `dfs = {ticker: df_portfolio[df_portfolio['ticker'] == ticker].copy() for ticker in my_tickers}`

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't think I fully understand your comment. I expected that the two lines of code would save the new dataframe. Before and when at the beginning of the itteration it would take a new dataframe and apply the code. Isn't df based on df_list?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better way to write my code using the groupby function instead of splitting my dataframe.